# StandardSetController is returning no results when using setFilterId, even though this list view does return results

Tags: apex, visualforce, list-view

I have an Opportunity listview which returns 5 results but when I try to use this in the ApexPages.StandardSetController the getResultSize() call returns zero.

Here is the code that is called once the user has selected a list view from the drop down:

```
public void refreshOptyList(){
    list<Opportunity> testList = new list<Opportunity>();

    optyList.clear();
    isSuccess = false;
    tooManyResults = false;
    if (filterId <> null && filterId<> 'None'){
         optySetController.setFilterId(filterId);
         testList = (list<Opportunity>)optySetController.getRecords();
         searchPerformed = true;
    } else searchPerformed = false;

    System.debug('Filter used=>'+filterId);
    System.debug('Result #=>'+optySetController.getResultSize());

    Integer counter=0;
    for (Opportunity opty:testList){
        optyList.add(new cOpty(Opty));
        counter++;
        if (counter==999){
            tooManyResults=true;
             break;
        }
    }



}
```

The filter id in the debug log is the correct one and the getResultSize() returns zero.

The filters for the list view are as follows:

- Custom Date Field >= 01/01/2015
- Custom Lookup To Account = hard coded string
- Stage != Won, Not Won
- Owner Full Name = "Lastname, Firstname"

Owner filter is set to "All Opportunities" and the list view is "Visible to all users".

**Update**

The StandardSetController is instantiated in the constructor of the class:

```
public MassReassignOpportunitiesController(){

    //Variable Init
    optyQueryString = 'SELECT name,StageName,Ownerid,CloseDate from Opportunity where isDeleted=false';
    optyList = new List<cOpty>();
    optySetController = new ApexPages.Standardsetcontroller(Database.getQueryLocator(optyQueryString+' limit 1000'));
}
```

I should also mention that selecting other list views does return results - I can't yet find a pattern to this though...

Comment: Where do you instantiate your controller optySetController?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use the getQueryLocator as opposed to the query method? https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008oIlIAI

Comment: This code is actually part of the Mass Transfer/Reassign Opps app from SF labs: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003JEIpEAO So I don't know why they decided to use getQueryLocator I'm afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved.

There appears to be some form of bug with using the Owner Full Name field.

I removed this filter:

- Owner Full Name = "Lastname, Firstname"

and added these 2 filters instead:

- Owner First Name = Firstname
- Owner Last Name = Lastname

And now the results are being returned as expected.